# ip camera seems to not request a IP via DHCP; orange lamp on the Ethernet port stops blinking after slight audible "crack"

Tags: networking, ip-camera

I want to test the plain functionality of my IP camera. My camera is currently connected to my router with an Ethernet cable. Unfortunately I don't have a manual - but if I understood [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79690/117978) answer correctly, then my IP camera should request an IP using DHCP automatically.

As i have no direct LAN connection to the camera, i should be able to get the IP via:

`nmap -sP "192.168.1.*"` which [should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13669860) present me all IP addresses from the local Network. I receive:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-23 15:08 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0033s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.10
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 2.62 seconds
```

`192.168.1.1` is my router, as i can connect to my router's configuration site with that ip.

`192.168.1.10` is my local notebook, as ifconfig tells me:

```
% sudo ifconfig | grep -A 1 wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:88:b4:76:09:80  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

**the most important thing:** After powering the IP camera up, all lamps, inclusive those of the Ethernet port are lightening. After some seconds the orange lamp blinks and after about 10 seconds after a slight audible "crack" it stops blinking. So i doubt that everything is fine here.

==> How can i verify that my camera is working correctly?

Comment: Look in the manual for your camera. It will tell you what the lights mean.

Comment: @DavidPostill Like i've said, i don't have a manual for the camera. The Camera is a gift and even the person I got it from doesn't have a manual for that.

Comment: Do you have the make and model number?

Comment: Yeah, it's "dbpower va033k+" but i couldn't find a manual or sth similar on http://www.dbpower.co.uk .

Comment: The device comes with a CD containing software and the manual. Do you (or the person who gave it to you) not have the CD?